# Full width banner in Gantry5 joomla framework

Tags: css

I am trying to create full width banner on a Joomla site which is sitting on Gantry5 framework. Tried to do some css work with no luck. 
Here is the url http://tinyurl.com/ptponmd

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: Which code you want me to paste? Its a module in CMS

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Joomla, but what am saying is generic to all CMS.

---

One solution, will be to add a custom region in your theme template and place slideshow there or print the slide directly in the template.

Here, all contents are wrapped with some 70% width using class"g-container"
If you inspect your site, you will see a section with id="g-navigation" and below that a div with class="g-container". 
If you can create a new region and print you slide show inside the Section id="g-container" but above div class="g-container". You will get full 100% width.

Please refer the image, for better understanding http://prntscr.com/7qt0u9

Hope this helps!

Comment: what if i update my theme/template? Will it override my code?

Comment: Adding extra lines in template, if done properly, won't break any other code.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try doing that.